# Get property name and value only if there is a value

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to simulate a .csv file with a list of property names as a header row followed by the actual list of properties for a list of items.

Currently, I have it working, but now there is a need to only include the properties' header and value where the item has a value for that property **anywhere in the list**.

This is what I have currently:

```
public static string LeadsToCSVString(List<Lead> leads)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Lead).GetProperties();
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => x.Name)));

    foreach (Lead lead in leads)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(lead))));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Where `Lead` is:

```
public class Lead
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsOk { get; set; }
}
```

The `List<Lead>` isn't guaranteed to have a value for all property values and there can even be a case where there is no value for a property like below:

```
FirstName,LastName,IsOK
Joe,,false
Adam,,true
```

What needs to be done is to only have header values and row column values where the property has an actual value. If I take the above example list, the CSV string would look like:

```
FirstName,IsOk
Joe,false
Adam,true
```

How can I modify my code to do this?

Some examples of what should happen if any object in the list has a value for the property:

```
FirstName,LastName,IsOK
Joe,Dirt,
Adam,,true

FirstName,LastName,IsOK
,Dirt,
Adam,,true
```

Comment: _"How can I modify my code to do this?"_ -- **what have you tried?** Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Question authors are expected to have made some attempt to solve their problems themselves, so that questions can be _specific_. Provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried already, and explain what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: As a hint: note that you will have to inspect every object in your list and determine which properties are present, before you build even the first row in your CSV. So... **do that**.

Comment: In addition to @PeterDuniho comments you should think what you mean with "bool property does not have value" (or int/any other value type) as you don't seem to be using nullable values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "has a value" means that its value is not null (which only works for reference types and Nullable value types), you could just filter out the ones that don't have any values in the list:

```
var filteredProps = properties.Where(p => leads.Any(l => p.GetValue(l) != null));
```

..and then use `filteredProps` instead of `properties`:

```
public static string LeadsToCSVString(List<Lead> leads)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Lead).GetProperties();

    var filteredProps = properties.Where(p => leads.Any(l => p.GetValue(l) != null));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", filteredProps.Select(x => x.Name)));

    foreach (Lead lead in leads)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", filteredProps.Select(x => x.GetValue(lead))));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Or to avoid calling `GetValue()` twice, you could create a dictionary (or a Lookup) of the properties and their values:

```
public static string LeadsToCSVString(List<Lead> leads)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Lead).GetProperties();

    var propsDictionary =
        properties.ToDictionary(p => p, p => leads.Select(l => p.GetValue(l)).ToArray())
        .Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(o => o != null))
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.Name)));

    foreach (Lead lead in leads)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(
            string.Join(",", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.GetValue(lead))));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful.